# Bootstrap tab: have unknown space between tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am puzzled by the space between Bootstrap tabs in my particular case.

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and Ace Theme (http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR) for a web application.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs " id="my-tabs">
          <li><a href="#page-1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#page-2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#page-3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content" id="my-panes">

        <div class="tab-pane" id="page-1">
            tab 1
        </div>  

        <div class="tab-pane" id="page-2">
            tab 2
        </div> 

        <div class="tab-pane" id="page-3">
            tab 3
        </div> 

    </div>
```

Here is my additional CSS:

```
#my-tabs.nav-tabs > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}


#my-tabs.nav-tabs > li > a {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin:0;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edAVC/5/

There is space between tabs. I am puzzled by this. Spend a few hours and unable to figure out why it is there. I want to remove the space between tabs.

Please note that I have to use display: inline-block for `<li>` element for other reasons.

Let's assume no changes to my css and HTML. What additional CSS I can add to remove the space between tabs?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a margin right being set in `bootstrap-combined.min.css`.

Try this

```
#my-tabs.nav-tabs > li > a {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin:0;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edAVC/7/)

Comment: Thanks soooo much for pointing out the css rule in bootstrap-combined.min.css. Before posting, I used FF and Chrome and was unable to find it. May I know which CSS selector in bootstrap-combined.min.css you are referring to? Why do I have to use negative margin values? Zero value does not work? Thanks!

Comment: @curious1 no worries! the selector was `.nav-tabs>li>a, .nav-pills>li>a` and it had `margin-right: 2px`

Answer (score 3):

> It's just the way setting elements on a line works. You want spaces between words that you type to be spaces right? The spaces between these blocks are just like spaces between words. *-[Source](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)*

According to this post your options are:

- Set a negative margin to remove the inline space
- Set font-size 0 on the ul, with a few issues documented
- or just use a float instead of display inline-block anyway